# Does the order in which the labels are defined matter?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to create a simple linked list in assembly, but I realized that if I change the order in which I define the labels, the code doesn't display the correct result. So I'm thinking, does the order in which I define the labels matter? Or does the order matter in this isolated case.

Code that works correctly:

```
%define OFFSET 8
%define SCALE 2

global _start

section .text

x1: 
    dq x2
    dq 48 ;; Zero

x2:
    dq x3
    dq 49 ;; One

x3:
    dq x4
    dq 50 ;; Two

x4:
    dq x5
    dq 51 ;; Three

x5:
    dq 0
    dq 52 ;; Four

end: 
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

_start:
    mov r8, 0

    .loop:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [x1 + r8 * SCALE + OFFSET] 
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        
        cmp qword [x1 + r8 * SCALE], 0 
        jz end
        add r8, OFFSET
    jmp .loop
```

Code that doesn't work properly (I changed the x1 position):

```
%define OFFSET 8
%define SCALE 2

global _start

section .text

x2:
    dq x3
    dq 49 ;; One

x3:
    dq x4
    dq 50 ;; Two

x4:
    dq x5
    dq 51 ;; Three

x5:
    dq 0
    dq 52 ;; Four

x1: 
    dq x2
    dq 48 ;; Zero

end: 
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

_start:
    mov r8, 0

    .loop:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [x1 + r8 * SCALE + OFFSET] 
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        
        cmp qword [x1 + r8 * SCALE], 0 
        jz end
        add r8, OFFSET
    jmp .loop
```

Comment: You aren't following the links at all; you're treating the memory data as an array, starting at `x1` and proceeding until you see a zero link (which will happen only by random chance in the second version, since `x5` is earlier in memory and will never be visited).  And note that `dq` produces *eight-byte values* in memory - `SCALE` should be 16 to actually step through your nodes in the array.

Comment: Yes, bytes are assembled into the output sections in the order you define them.  So code that loop over data as an array will access it in source order.  The labels themselves actually don't matter, other than the one your code references (`x1`), so what matters are the `dq` statements.  (This data looks like a linked list, and the loop termination condition is also designed for a linked list, though.) BTW, `'0'` is a clearer way to write `48` which doesn't need a comment to remind the reader that it's the ASCII code for zero.

Comment: @jasonharper: x86 addressing modes only have room for a 2-bit shift count, so scale factors from 1 to 8, not 16.  The OP's combination of `SCALE = 2` and `OFFSET = 8` works (note the `add r8, OFFSET`), although the semantic meaning seems wrong; that seems to imply 2-byte elements as you say.  It would make sense to use `SCALE equ 8` and  `OFFSET equ 2`, with `lea rsi, [x1 + r8 * SCALE + OFFSET]` changed to `lea rsi, [x1 + r8 * SCALE + SCALE]`.  Of course if you were traversing this as a linked list, `OFFSET` wouldn't be part of this, you'd just have `lea rsi, [r8 + char_offset]` or something.

Comment: Thank you both for your explanations, now things are clearer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments into an answer proper:

> Does the order in which the labels are defined matter?

No, the ordering of labels by themselves does not matter keeping in mind

- (prior NASM version 2.14) a `global` label declaration must occur *before* the definition the respective label, and
- local label definitions shorthand (`.my_local_label`) is with respect to the most recent global label.

> […] if I change the order in which I define the labels, […] I changed the x1 position […]

Yes *and* you have also moved the `dq` data.
There are *two* changes, not just moving a label location.
Just like the order you write down instructions matters, the order of any other data matters too.
The textual order (of everything *belonging* to *one* `section`) defines *the order* in memory.

> I'm trying to create a [singly‑]linked list in assembly […]

As [Jason Harper](/q/77991922#comment137495529_77991922) highlighted, a singly‑linked list means storing and retrieving a (payload, pointer) tuple and following the address `pointer` indicates.

> ```
>         lea rsi, [x1 + r8 * SCALE + OFFSET]
> ```

This is *a pattern* for accessing an array data structure, i. e. a *contiguous* sequence of Bytes in memory.
For a singly‑linked list, you need to retrieve contents from memory *and* treat the pointer part of the just retrieved data as an address.
How does this look like?

```
    mov rsi, x1
    ; now `rsi` contains _the address_ the label `x1` points to
    
    mov rcx, [rsi + 0]  ; retrieve 8 Bytes located at `rsi`
    mov rsi, [rsi + 8]  ; retrieve 8 Bytes located at `rsi + 8`
```

Now `rcx` contains the first eight Bytes at `x1` (i. e. the pointer part), so if you *use* its value

```
    mov rcx, [rcx]
```

you have *followed* a pointer.
After this instruction `rcx` contains the contents found at the memory location the `x1` item pointed to (presuming it was not a null‑pointer).
I will leave it up to you to wrap everything neatly into a loop.

> ```
>         cmp qword [x1 + r8 * SCALE], 0 
>         jz end
> ```

`rcx` is a nice register to store pointers in because then you can use the `jrcxz` (jump if `rcx` is zero) instruction.

Comment: *a `global` label declaration must occur before the definition the respective label* - No, anywhere in the same file is equivalent for NASM.  Before or after, the symbol is visible in the `.o` for linking.

Comment: `jrcxz` is 2 uops on Intel CPUs, vs. 1 uop for `test rcx,rcx/jz` (two instructions which macro-fuses into one uop).  `jrcxz` is smaller, but slower except on AMD.  https://uops.info/  It's surprisingly slow on Intel E-cores, although that could perhaps be an artifact of microbenchmarking a dense sequence of back-to-back branches filling up the branch predictor.  https://uops.info/html-tp/ADL-E/JRCXZ_Rel8-Measurements.html measured it on Alder Lake E-cores (Gracemont) as about 1 per 8.5 cycles taken, or one per 21.5 cycles not-taken.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, thanks. I must have read the documentation [before 2018](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/commit/d558598ebe15279f346f748e8581de24ca63a0c1) when `global` indeed had to appear before the definition.

Comment: I hadn't realized it was a semi-recent change, thanks for linking the changelog!  I guess at the time I got curious and tried it, it was post 2018.  And/or I was remembering trying the same thing with GAS `.global`, which (at least these days) also can precede or follow a label or `.set`.